# How to prevent overriding of div in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two fixed rows.In first one there is a image and in second one there is a menu bar. when i am trying to add next row (which will contain another image file) below that two fixed row, the image file overrides to the first row (fixed row). Someone please help me!
Thank You.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="width:100%">
              <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="images/logo.png"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" >
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs navbar-inverse">

                                        <li style="margin-right:15px"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                                        <li style="margin-right:15px"><a href="aims.html">Our AIMS</a></li>
                                        <li style="margin-right:15px"><a href="mission.html">Mission</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </nav>
    </div>

            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="images/sideImg.jpg" alt="save humanity">
                     </div>
                </div>

            </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the container of the first two rows is fixed, it is out of the normal flow of the document. You will need to add `padding-top` to the third div/row which is `>` the height of the first two rows/container.

**HTML**

```
<div class="third-row"> <!-- Add custom div wrapping the container -->
  <div class="container">
```

**CSS**

```
.third-row {
  padding-top: 150px;
}
```

**Output:**

```css
.third-row {
  padding-top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="width:100%">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs navbar-inverse">

            <li style="margin-right:15px"><a href="home.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li style="margin-right:15px"><a href="aims.html">Our AIMS</a>
            </li>
            <li style="margin-right:15px"><a href="mission.html">Mission</a>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="third-row">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/1200x300" alt="save humanity">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't think altering default classes of **Bootstrap** is a good idea.

Comment: I have not altered any default class of Bootstrap here :) Just added a custom class to the markup and used it in CSS.

Comment: My apologize, I've just studied whole Que and since the OP using `navbar-fixed-top`, then using `padding-top` will be a good solution, but instead of adding class in container we can create a `wrapper` of third `container` and add the `padding` to that `wrapper` will be a better one.

Comment: We can also add `padding-top` to body as well. Since you have suggested to do that, I will add a wrapper.

Comment: This Idea works for md, lg and sm devices, NOT for xs ! @Manoj Kumar

Comment: I am not sure how your other code looks like. If you run this code snippet, it works for xs devices as well. Please edit with your live implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Try as following example .

**HTML**

```
<div class="row custom">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.custom{
  //your codes 
  }
```